# Facing issue - bad interpreter: No such file or directory when used pod update on MAC

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Getting error like:

-bash: /usr/local/bin/pod: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I have tried to use *sudo gem install cocoapods* but it is giving

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.0/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200605-20675-yfsgd0.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

Please help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Please find answer below, as there are answers in different thread but it leads to another issue. Hope this will be useful to all who faces this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to know that it is due to xcode installation issue. so have to agree to term

step 1: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

step 2: sudo gem install cocoapods (use sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin if you get permission issue)

step 3: pod update